# OpenCV : java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror native method not found by Highgui.imread on Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have already loaded the OpenCV libraries from the main class, and I used Highgui.imread in another class. I am not sure why I am still having this problem when the library has been loaded successfully.  Am I missing something or did I do something wrong?

Main Class - I've done static initialization

```
static {
    if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
    } else {
        Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
    }
}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this){
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (status){
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i("Success", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }   
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}
```

The class that uses Highgui.imread - the imageName is the string path name for the image

```
public void transformImage(){
    image = Highgui.imread(imageName);      
    try {
        image.convertTo(secondImage, CvType.CV_64FC1);

        int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.rows());
        int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.cols()); // on the border add zero values

        Mat padded = new Mat(new Size(n, m), CvType.CV_64FC1); // expand input image to optimal size

        Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(image, padded, 0, m - image.rows(), 0, n - image.cols(), Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);

        List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        planes.add(padded);
        planes.add(Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1));

        Mat complexI = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);

        Mat complexI2 = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);

        Core.merge(planes, complexI); // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros

        Core.dct(complexI, complexI2); // this way the result may fit in the source matrix

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Blargh", e.toString());
    }
}
```

The logcat error is

> 04-06 18:22:54.420: W/dalvikvm(4906): No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/highgui/Highgui;.imread_1:(Ljava/lang/String;)J
>   04-06 18:22:54.420: D/AndroidRuntime(4906): Shutting down VM
>   04-06 18:22:54.420: W/dalvikvm(4906): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e32700)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1:(Ljava/lang/String;)J
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Native Method)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:359)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.sherlynn.invisiblewatermarkapp.DiscreteCosineTransformAlgorithm.transformImage(DiscreteCosineTransformAlgorithm.java:44)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.sherlynn.invisiblewatermarkapp.WatermarkActivity.onCreate(WatermarkActivity.java:49)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   04-06 18:22:54.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

** Updated problem : I have tested with other phones (S4 and Note 2), and apparently they do not throw this error. I tested back with my phone (S3)'s front camera, and it didn't throw me this error. I then tested with the rear camera, but with the lower megapixels, and it worked. Somehow, it doesn't work with the highest megapixel in my S3 which is 8 megapixels but it works on Note 2 and S4 on high megapixel. If anyone might have encountered this or have any solution to solve this, it would be utmost appreciated. For the time being, I shall continue using the lower megapixel. :)

Comment: Post your code and detailed error log please.